# How to let a Maven module have dependency on another Maven module through the pom of a master project?

Tags: java, maven, project

#### objective::

- give::

  3 projects `AA, BB, CC`; under developing.

  `AA` = master project

  **`CC` depends on `BB`**
- requirement::

  I dont want to modify the subprojects.

  I want to manage the dependency in a master project `AA`.

  ie: **add dependency through the `pom` in `AA`, not in `BB or CC`.**

#### problem::

so I use `Maven module`, and I tried this, didnt work::

1. link the modules together in `AA`.

```xml
    <modules>
        <module>../BB</module>
        <module>../CC</module>
    </modules>
```

2. but then, `CC` is not able to import `ClassB` from `BB`.

[image]

=> **How can I make `CC` depends on `BB` when only editing the `pom` in `AA`?**

---

#### the common solution (that I try to avoid)::

I do know that, if I add dependency in the pom of `CC`, everything is fine, but I dont want to do this::

1. add dependency in the pom of `CC`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>GG</groupId>
            <artifactId>BB</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

2. now, `CC` is able to import `ClassB` from `BB`.

[image]

- btw: some online answers say you need `maven install` then add the `jar`.

  1. here, I dont want to build a `jar` of `BB`. (as it wouldnt & dont-need-to produce a `jar` even if you use the "common solution" I wrote above.)

     cuz `BB` is under developing, it will be constantly modified.
  2. even if I use `jar`, I dont see how it helps in my case.
- (in this case, the master project `AA` for `<parent>` in `CC` may not even be needed.)

---

Some resource that I looked through, I dont know why in my case it doesnt work::

Did I understand `Maven module` wrong?

<sub>[How do I add a project as a dependency of another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383322/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_multi_module

[how to add dependency of other maven project to my current maven project in java eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208765/how-to-add-dependency-of-other-maven-project-to-my-current-maven-project-in-java)

[How can a maven project depend on another local maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684467/how-can-a-maven-project-depend-on-another-local-maven-project)</sub>

Comment: First `I dont want to modify the subprojects.` Why? If you have a dependency you have to add that dependency. That's it. Simple as it. Furthermore the images are a bad idea better use text.

Answer (score 0):

Create a structure like this:

```
root-directory
  +--- pom.xml
  +--- module-BB
          +-- src
          +-- pom.xml
  +--- module-CC
          +-- src
          +-- pom.xml
```

In mdoule `CC` you can simply define a dependency to `module BB` and build the whole project from root via `mvn package`...

Comment: 1. for `I dont want to modify the subprojects`, I simply want to organize the dependencies in a master project, not in the subprojects. 
2. base on your answer & comment `If you have a dependency you have to add that dependency. That's it. Simple as it.`, `you can simply define a dependency to module BB`, seems like there is really no other way, but to modify on the subprojects.

Comment: [^ continue] I thought the use of `module` made managing through a master project possible. But now it seems like I understood `Maven module` totally wrong. 
(3. I added back few lines of text for the image. I forgot about that when I inserted the image. But wont matter now.)

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee (several modules) can be build from root and some of the modules (for example service https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee/blob/master/service/pom.xml) has a dependency to another module...this also indirectly defines the build order of the modules...